# Can't increase by 0.1 with `toFixed(1)` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create two methods: one for increasing the number by 0.1 and another one for decreasing by the same value. But I met an unexpected behavior for me: I can decrease the number properly using `number = (number - 0.1).toFixed(1);`, but when I'm trying to increase the number the same way (it works only once), I've got the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: (number + 0.1).toFixed is not a function"

Here is the code:

```js
var number = 0.5;
console.log('Number: ', number)

function increase() {
  if (number < 1) {
    number = (number + 0.1).toFixed(1);
    console.log('Number: ', number)
  }
}

function decrease() {
  if (number > 0) {
    number = (number - 0.1).toFixed(1);
    console.log('Number: ', number)
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
<button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
```

**My question is:** Why? And how should I correct my code, to repair my `increase` method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `toFixed()` returns a `string` and strings don't have a `toFixed()` method.

Comment: You have type confusion. `toFixed` returns a string, so your `number` variable starts out as a number and becomes a string after `increase` or `decrease`. Separate the state from the display (`number += 0.1; console.log('Number: ', number.toFixed(1));`).

Comment: But why the decreasing is working every time? Even if `toFixed(1)` returns a string

Comment: Subtraction only works on numbers, so it’ll convert the string, but `+` doubles as the string concatenation operator and converts the number.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide JavaScript automatically converts it from the `-`, where the `+` is interpreted as string concatenation.

Comment: Because `+` is overloaded to act on strings, but `-` is not.

Comment: So many answers in comments, thanks for your help, guys, now it's clear for me =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `toFixed()` method returns a `string` type, and `string` don't have a `toFixed()` method - resulting in the error of `.toFixed is not a function`.

To resolve, force the output from `toFixed()` back to a `number`. This can be done with `Number()` or the shorthand method of prepending `+`.

- `Number((0.1).toFixed())`
- `+(0.1).toFixed()`

```js
var number = 0.5;
console.log('Number: ', number)

function increase() {
  if (number < 1) {
    number = Number((number + 0.1).toFixed(1));
    console.log('Number: ', number)
  }
}

function decrease() {
  if (number > 0) {
    number = Number((number - 0.1).toFixed(1));
    console.log('Number: ', number)
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
<button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
```

Comment: This is correct solution. You need to transform string (received from .toFixed) into a number again for performing further math operations.

Answer (score 3):

The **return value** of `toFixed` method is a string, as mentioned in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

> **Return value:** A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.

So, when calling `increase` or `decrease` for the first time, the value of the variable `number` will be of type **string**.

After that when calling `increase`:

`number + 0.1` will be of type string, because **string + number** is a **string**, and `toFixed` is not a function of **string**s, and that's why you get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (number + 0.1).toFixed is not a function

However, `number - 0.1` will work, because **string - number** is a **number** and that's fine.

To solve this, you should keep your `number` of type **number**, and you can do this in multiple ways:

- Use the method [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

`number = parseFloat((number + 0.1).toFixed(1));`

- Use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object constructor:

`number = Number((number + 0.1).toFixed(1));`

- Use `+`:

`number = +((number + 0.1).toFixed(1));`

Comment: `parseFloat` seems to work too, thanks for your answer!